# R loop through name specific columns to check the value

Tags: r, loops

I want to achieve the following:

1. loop through all CHECK columns, sometimes there are more (up to 20). The same goes for data (will definitely more than 3 observations). feel free to use my variables CHECKnum, CHECKstart or CHECKend
2. check whether A001 is in it, if yes, return the column name, else return CHECK0

sample data

```r
mydf <- data.frame(case = c(1, 2, 3),
                   id = c(10, 11, 12),
                   CHECK1 = c("A001", "B001", "C001"),
                   CHECK2 = c("Z001", "B001", "C001"),
                   CHECK3 = c("Z001", "B001", "C001"),
                   CHECK4 = c("Z001", "B001", "A001"),
                   CHECK5 = c("Z001", "B001", "C001"))
```

Trial:

```r
CHECKnum = ifpol %>%
  colnames(.) %>%
  str_which("^CHECK") %>%
  length(.)
    
CHECKstart = which(colnames(ifpol) == "CHECK1")
CHECKend = CHECKstart + CHECKnum
    
for (i in 1:CHECKnum) {
  # giving out position and column name
  mydf = mydf %>% mutate(CHECK_Pos = case_when(mydf[paste0("CHECK", i)] == "A001" ~ i * 1,
                                               TRUE ~ 0),
                         CHECK_Name = case_when(mydf[paste0("CHECK", i)] == "A001" ~ paste0("CHECK", i),
                                               TRUE ~ "CHECK0"))
}
```

I want it to show something like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox38L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a base R option using `max.col` :

```
#Select the columns to check
cols <- grep('CHECK', names(mydf), value = TRUE)
#Compare the value
mat <- mydf[cols] == 'A001'
#Find the column name where the value exist in each row
mydf$result <- cols[max.col(mat)]
#If the value does not exist in the row turn to `NA`.
mydf$result[rowSums(mat) == 0] <- NA
mydf

#  case id CHECK1 CHECK2 CHECK3 CHECK4 CHECK5 result
#1    1 10   A001   Z001   Z001   Z001   Z001 CHECK1
#2    2 11   B001   B001   B001   B001   B001   <NA>
#3    3 12   C001   C001   C001   A001   C001 CHECK4
```

Comment: thanks for the help~!
but is there any easy tweak if i want the result i want to show is 1, NA then 4 instead of the full column name..
thanks!

Comment: @xiaobai5883 Replace the line `mydf$result <- cols[max.col(mat)]` with `mydf$result <- max.col(mat)`. Keeping everything else the same.

Comment: just one last question.. is there any easy tweak say i don't want exact match like A001 now.. i just want to check anything starts with A then is identified as match? is that possible? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**As a supplement**:
I think the long format is a nice option for this case.
Becase it's very clear to show the position "A001" and easy to filter even for more CHECK number.
I will use `data.table` as a demonstration.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)
dt <- melt(mydf, id = 1:2, measure.vars = patterns("CHECK*")) 
dt
```

Long format

```
    case id variable value
 1:    1 10   CHECK1  A001
 2:    2 11   CHECK1  B001
 3:    3 12   CHECK1  C001
 4:    1 10   CHECK2  Z001
 5:    2 11   CHECK2  B001
 6:    3 12   CHECK2  C001
 7:    1 10   CHECK3  Z001
 8:    2 11   CHECK3  B001
 9:    3 12   CHECK3  C001
10:    1 10   CHECK4  Z001
11:    2 11   CHECK4  B001
12:    3 12   CHECK4  A001
13:    1 10   CHECK5  Z001
14:    2 11   CHECK5  B001
15:    3 12   CHECK5  C001
```

Filter `A001`

```
dt[value == "A001"]
  case id variable value
1:    1 10   CHECK1  A001
2:    3 12   CHECK4  A001
```